# com.badlogic.gdx.utils.Array parameters for Constructor

Tags: java, libgdx

```
public Array (boolean ordered, int capacity, Class arrayType)
```

how do I call this constructor? I am trying this below

```
Array<Float> red = new Array<Float>(false,1,Float);
```

gives me an error on Float, isn't Float a class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need Float.class bud, that actually returns the object that represents the Float class.